# Account deletion

Tags: support, user-accounts

Ok.

I previously asked to have my account deleted.

However, the account was not deleted. My rep points were deleted, but not the account.

Anyway, meanwhile I am quoted,

> 2 Might want to also read: bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1549/… – Benzo Jul 13 at 14:07

So, please return rep points to me and others impacted by my earlier withdrawal from bicycles.stackexchange.

Comment: It looks like your account was deleted and you created a new account. Since only your bicycles.SE account was deleted and not the rest of your SE accounts, simply trying to log in probably created a new account and associated it with your account elsewhere on the SE network (copying profile information over). All your old posts now show a ghost-like "user313", like this: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/5980 or this: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/9390

Comment: I never created a new account. Same one. Points deleted.

Comment: Thanks feeiheit. I see the ghost-like stuff. Don't you think that the ghost should still keep the points?

Comment: "Since only your bicycles.SE account was deleted and not the rest of your SE accounts, **simply trying to log in**..." did in fact create a new account. But all the associated data, except the actual text of your posts, *is* gone.

Comment: It's a little late, but why delete your account if you want to keep your rep points?

Comment: I did not "log in". I clicked on an old tab. I'm ok with deleted rep. However, if wdypdx22 appears on this site, I expect full reputation. Also, "user313" actually did contribute to the site.

Comment: If you have cookies enabled, and you were logged in to another SE site, and came here, you logged in again. Remember the notification bar at the top of your browser that said, "Welcome back, wdypdx22, you have been logged in. Click here to refresh the page." That meant that you logged in. Regardless, there is no way to recover the data that was attached to your account. For that matter, you chose to be deleted, and cost a lot of other users rep in the process. I see know reason to allow you the opportunity to do it again.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real "undelete" - if you asked for your account to be deleted, and it was, then it's *gone*.

That said, we might be able to get your old posts re-associated with your new account, which will restore at least some of your former reputation.

Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of each page, and send us a request - we'll do our best to verify ownership and get you fixed up.

Comment: @wdypdx22: as freiheit mentioned, the *posts themselves* (or at least, some of them) remain - there are a number of rules that govern the deletion of posts, and they're *mostly* independent from those governing the deletion of users. Ditto for comments, edits, tags... But there's no profile linking your former posts together, your favorites are gone, votes, badges, information on any tags you created, bounties you offered, etc. are gone. Pretty much all I can do is re-associate the posts, since they all have that "user313" placeholder text where the author should be.

Answer (score -2):

I don't care about the rep points. Just didn't realize that deleting my account would impact others. Oh well, shit happens.

My thought was that my account would simply get "grayed out"...and that everything else would remain intact except for the user-name.

Somehow, my previous account got above 5,000 points due to my stupidity. I'm now at 101 due to my stupidity.